# Method won't return value to the screen

Tags: c#, methods

I'm still a beginner and I'm doing simple projects. The one I'm currently doing is a simple method that asks the user to enter a number 1-10. If they don't it'll keep asking till the requirement is met, then return the value. It doesn't though, please help.Thank you.

```
namespace Practice
{ 

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetNumberFromUser();
            Console.Read();
        }

        static int GetNumberFromUser()
        {
            int userNumber = 0;

            while (userNumber < 1 || userNumber > 10)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a number between 1 and 10: ");
                string usersResponse = Console.ReadLine();
                userNumber = Convert.ToInt32(usersResponse);
            }

            return userNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd better validating the input because if the input is not a integer, it might cause exception. Pretty small advice tho :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to print the return value of the GetNumberFromUser() method in the main() method.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetNumberFromUser());           
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the returned value to a variable from the method like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int input = GetNumberFromUser();
    Console.Read();
}
```

After this you can use the `input` variable according to your need

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You have to print the value returned in console.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var i = GetNumberFromUser();
        Console.Write(i);
        Console.Read();
    }

    static int GetNumberFromUser()
    {
        int userNumber = 0;

        while (userNumber < 1 || userNumber > 10)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a number between 1 and 10: ");
            string usersResponse = Console.ReadLine();
            userNumber = Convert.ToInt32(usersResponse);
        }

        return userNumber;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't print the integer out.

Why not using a int variable to store the return value of method GetNumberFromUser() and print the value?

You declared the return value of method GetNumberFromUser() is integer; If you don't want to return anything, just replace the

> int

with

> void

The method will be still executed once it's called.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

        var res = GetNumberFromUser();
        Console.WriteLine(res);

        Console.ReadKey();
 }
```